# Upgrade ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, update

I have a bunch of old machines in production all running uBuntu 9.10. I want to now upgrade this to 10.04 distributions but I am getting the following error (because the repositories have expired I guess)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  update-manager-core: Depends: python-apt (>= 0.7.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

All my apt-get update / apt-get upgrade commands are failing with error

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/restricted Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/universe Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/restricted Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/restricted Sources
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/universe Packages
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Sources
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/universe Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone help me with next steps and how I can fix this. If there is any PPA or any other repository maintaining update-manager-core with all dependencies, then I am happy to use that.

Thanks
Sparsh Gupta

Comment: Looks like you're on 9.04, not 9.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case [LucidUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades) is not working anymore, go straight from Jaunty to Lucid and skip Karmic. make a backup of valuable data first,

As root run:

```
cd /etc/apt
perl -i.bak -pe 's/jaunty/lucid/' sources.list
aptitude update
aptitude dist-upgrade
```

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` is preferred.  See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/installing-upgrading.html).